# Get back @html.dropdownlist ID value for database insert / update in Webmatrix

Tags: database, razor, webmatrix, html-select

I have build some dropdown lists using the LINK to Objects method and @html.dropdownlist Webmatrix helper. This works fine.

I want to know `how to pass / store the selected value in my database table`.

**Build of items list in code section**

```
var titlesData = db.Query("SELECT TitleId, Name FROM Titles ORDER BY Name");
        titlesListItems = titlesData.Select(i => new SelectListItem {
        Value = i.TitleId.ToString(),
        Text = i.Name,
        Selected = i.TitleId == providerData.TitleId ? true : false
        });
```

**HTML markup section:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("titlesCombo","-- Veuillez sélectionner -- ",titlesListItems)
```

**Database update command (see the ???)**:

```
db.Execute("UPDATE Providers SET TitleId=@0 WHERE ProviderId=@1",???,providerId)
```

The method I used for now is to create another variable:

```
var titleId = "";

if (!IsPost) {

    titleId = providerData.TitleId.ToString(); //providerData stores the SQL query result
}

if (IsPost) {

    var titleId = Request.Form[TitleID]
    db.Execute("UPDATE Providers SET TitleId=@0 WHERE ProviderId=@1",titleId,providerId)
}
```

**Unfortunately, data doesn't get updated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you haven't referenced rightly the DropDownList helper in your code.
Try with the following code:

```
var titleId = ""; 

if (!IsPost) { 
    titleId = providerData.TitleId.ToString();
} 

if (IsPost) { 
    titleId = Request.Form["titlesCombo"];
    db.Execute("UPDATE Providers SET TitleId=@0 WHERE ProviderId=@1",titleId,providerId);
}
```

Comment: By the way,  can you confirm that the titleId in the (!IsPOst) condition can be removed since value will anyway appear because of the  @Html.DropDownList selected item ?